# Is it possible to change params through web?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I am coding a website, that have no legit option for editing users.
Once created, nothing can be changed.

And here is my question:
Is it possible to change users data (for example by sending patch requests) without using edit form (because I did not create one), by 3rd party (a.k.a. not host)?

As Rails 5 requires, I am using strong params (sending user name and password when creating user by signup form).

@routes

```
     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
     root GET    /                         sessions#new
   signup GET    /signup(.:format)         users#new
          POST   /signup(.:format)         users#create
    login GET    /login(.:format)          sessions#new
          POST   /login(.:format)          sessions#create
   logout DELETE /logout(.:format)         sessions#destroy
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

Should also mention that there is no update method, but I am using

```
resources :users
```

Comment: You didn't create a form, but does a update method exist?

Comment: If you can access the database using rails console, you can alter the data.

Comment: Do you have routes that update the user? There's no way of knowing how your app is set up, so I'm not sure what you're expecting for an answer.

Comment: And if you can access the database you can too -I'm not sure how this helps the OP.

Comment: No, it does not. Added routes for clarity

Comment: As I mentioned, I am talking about 3rd party, so for example random user.

Comment: Would that made a difference, if it existed but was empty? @spickermann

Comment: If there is no `update` method in your controller you really should be saying `resources :users, :except => %i[update]`; similarly for other controller methods that don't exist. Don't define routes that have no reason to exist.

Comment: Weird, my comment wasn't posted. Anyway... That's exactly what I needed to do. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For third party access to your db you probably need an API.

Simplified example:

You app's URL is https://myapp.example.com/.

config/routes.rb:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users, only: [:update]
  end
end
```

rake routes:

```
     Prefix Verb  URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
api_v1_user PATCH /api/v1/users/:id(.:format) api/v1/users#update
            PUT   /api/v1/users/:id(.:format) api/v1/users#update
```

app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb:

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def update
    # check params, maybe look for some security tokens

    user = User.find(params[:id])
    if user
      user.update_attribute(:name, params[:name])
      render plain: "success" and return
    else
      render plain: "failure" and return
    end
  end
end
```

Then request like this

```
curl -X PATCH https://myapp.example.com/api/v1/users/1?name=new_name
```

would change `users`' with id = 1 `name` by "new_name".

For proper API desing you may check http://jsonapi.org/.

Comment: So if I don't create API like this, this curl command won't work? Because behavior like this is unwanted in my app.

Comment: Any request has to be processed by some properly routed controller, so yes, if there are no controllers like this, curl won't work. And why exactly this behaviour is unwanted?

Comment: Because all data that user inputs while signing up are permanent ones and there is no need to change them. That's why I don't want any 3rd party to change them. Especially without my knowledge.

Comment: Would it make any difference, if update method existed, but it would be empty? @Alexander-Morozow

Comment: I don't understand: original question was "Is it possible to change users data ... by 3rd party ...?". Now you don't want anything to change. If you don't want anything to change, just don't create methods that changes anything.

Comment: I did not create one. But I had one bug. I just limited resources to few methods that I am using and it looks better now.